# What to do when I do not get enough fill in cash leg during cash - future arbitrage

Tags: spread

Futures have fixed lot sizes in my exchange, but cash do not. When I am spread trading the cash - future pair, what should I do if I am unable to get enough fill on the cash side.

Comment: Depends on how you get into the spot.

Comment: I am identifying a profitable spread buy or spread sell, then checking if enough quantity is present for my target prices on both legs, and firing the trades. Of course, many times, I might not actually get a fill, and this happens especially on the cash leg. My question is, what would be a good way to minimize my damage once I get a partial fill.